# How to sort the firebase json object inside object sort in the angular js.I tried default filter and custom filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am
    working on
    angular js
    project in this i am using fire-base.
        In the response i am getting the below json format.
        I want to sort descending order by date.
        I tried orderBy default filters.Here that is not correctly filtered.In this code any problem.

```
    Json structure:
    {
    {
    "-KKRkKGG0-rUrWU9l0DQ":{
    "actual_message":"ahsio",
    "message_date":"Jun 17, 10:36",
    "posted_to":"School Admin",
    },
    "-KKRkR6QBT8FkdzXeNTJ":{
    ".priority":"null",
    "actual_message":"T",
    "message_date":"Jun 17, 10:36",
    }
    }







   <tbody ng-repeat="(key,value) in MainItems"style="border-top: none">
  <tr ng-repeat="(key1,value1) in value    |orderBy:message_date"style="background:#ffffff">
```

Comment: Show us your html code

Comment: "message_date":"Jun 17, 10:36",  is there a problem date format

Comment: I tried a lot not working i dont is it date format problem